# Отличается шрифт на компе и на андроиде

Tags: android, java

Устанавливаю сторонний шрифт в TextView, но на эмуляторе и на смартфоне он выглядит почему-то по другому.

Вот [так](http://pic2net.r/?i=20130710acef417b412cc52840bcd87292fb5862.jpg) выглядит на эмуляторе.

А [вот](http://pic2net.ru/view/v/20130710f3ad9f7ed6df554703850a1fc5307500.jpg) сам шрифт.

Код который устанавливает шрифт выглядит так:

```
TextView txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.headText);
    final Typeface Font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "HelveticaNeueMedium.ttf");
    txt.setTypeface(Font);
```

Comment: смотри результат на девайсе

Comment: Что-то в Вашем шрифте кириллических символов не видно - они там вообще есть?